# How to set the title of on navigatonitem when I click on each row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hello friends I am new to TableView.....I want help..please

I have to set the title on navigation bar  when I click on each row I should get the same name of a row on naviagtionbar...... friends I have 23 rows in my table so please suggest me to get my problem to solved please......

Thanks & rega

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tableView:didSelectRowForIndexPath:`, write the following code:

```
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Hello alex you can set custom back button on it                                                                      btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(280, 0, 32, 31);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.title = nameoftherow; [self.view setNeedsDisplay];` in `tableView:didSelectRowForIndexPath:`.